# Analysing large data set in Oracle Database do it in Memory or Iterative Query?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, perl, data-analysis

All,

Note for simplicity I have created the following scenario below to aid in the question, which is as close to the real problem I am having.

There is a table called "**State**" that for all intents and purposes holds a value that relates to another table called "**Stock**" which holds data about an object.

e.g.

```
+-----+-------+
|TABLE| VALUE |
+-----+-------+
|Stock| Ball  |
+-----+-------+
|State|Instock|
+-----+-------+
```

So from above case, a record called "Ball" in the Stock table is "Instock" according to the State table.

However to get to this conclusion I need to analyse another table called Items which is a true value of how many physical items of that stock exist in the real world So if there are items or no items available this will affect the value in the State table that relates to that Stock record.

Now to analyse this and modify the state, I need to start from the State table and navigate to the Items table via the Stock table like so

```
State ----> Stock ----> Items
```

Now there is a lot of records in this table which all need to be monitored at least daily.

I have never embarked on something like this before however my intuition is telling me I could just get all the tables and load them as data objects into my analysis application and in memory form the relationships virtually.

So all I would need to do is one big query at the start and load all the SQL results into memory. Is this possible or wise?

However the other option I considered is just iteration through each records like so. Doing many transactions sequentially.

```
State record 1 ----> Stock record 1 ----> Analyse Items records --> Update State record 1
State record 2 ----> Stock record 2 ----> Analyse Items records --> Updates State record 2
.......
```

Are either of these ways a good option or is there another way to do this?

**Constraints**

- Oracle 11g Database
- Cannot change schema or tables
- Thinking of using **Java** or **Perl** for this analysing application
- This application will be external and not in the same physical location as the DB

**Pseudo Code**

```
Get all state records in State table
Find their related records in Stock table
Find all child records of Stock table in Items table
Modify state of current record 
Move onto next record set.
```

So any guidance or specific methodologies / features I could utilise for this problem would be welcomed.

Please dont give me a solution just a little nudge in the right direction is all I ask :)

Comment: So to clarify, what is your end goal?  Is the end goal to update the state record with weather there are any items in stock?  How often will this run?

Comment: Also, can you give an estimate of how many rows there are in each table.

Comment: Of the data I am interested I will process daily on average 30,000 rows out of tables that have row counts in the millions.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to write a block of PL/SQL code, and then call it via a scheduled job.

Scheduler documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm

There is really no reason to handle this using Java or Perl, as this is just un-necessary connections, and configurations outside of the oracle environment.  Just one more app to remember to maintain whereas if it is in Oracle it will be easily accessable, and maintanable (still put it in source control though).

As for the actual query, this shouldn't bee too hard.  You could to a simple update statment depending on how many rows are in each table.  Something like

```
UPDATE STATE SET STATE.INSTOCK = TRUE 
    WHERE STATE.PK IN (
        SELECT ITEMS.STATEFK FROM ITEMS WHERE ITEMS.COUNT > 0
    );
```

Then do the same, but set to false where count <= 0.

This isn't correct syntax at all for PL/SQL, but should give you a general idea of how the query should work.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. I hope the DBAdmin wont mind me messing with his server.

Comment: Those pesky DBAdmins, always so protective of the data!  Ask them they have a sandbox environment, or could create one so you aren't messing with the production data.  Also, depending on the Admin's skill, they may be able to help you put together some PL/SQL.  I'm always amazed by the crazy stuff some of the DB people are able to whip together in no time at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would first say that the state table is a bad idea.  You already know the state based on the number of items, so as this changes (frequently), your state table has invalid (outdated) entries.  I also assume that you cannot change this structure, but simply need to maintain this state constantly.

I would run as a single update statement (ensure that you have sufficient rollback), but 30k rows affected is not very big.  For example:

```
> set serveroutput on
> drop table stock
table STOCK dropped.
> create table stock
(
stock_id number,
name varchar2(20)
)
table STOCK created.
> drop table item
table ITEM dropped.
> create table item
(
item_id number,
stock_id number,
num number
)
table ITEM created.
> drop table state
table STATE dropped.
> -- this really doesnt need to exist
> create table state
(
stock_id number,
val varchar2(20)
)
table STATE created.
> insert into stock values (1,'Ball')
1 rows inserted.
> insert into stock values (2,'Chair')
1 rows inserted.
> insert into stock values (3,'Pen')
1 rows inserted.
> insert into item (item_id, stock_id, num) values (1, 1, 35)
1 rows inserted.
> insert into item (item_id, stock_id, num) values (2, 2, 0)
1 rows inserted.
> insert into item (item_id, stock_id, num) values (3, 3, 1)
1 rows inserted.
> insert into state (stock_id, val) values (1, 'InStock')
1 rows inserted.
> insert into state (stock_id, val) values (2, 'OutOfStock')
1 rows inserted.
> insert into state (stock_id, val) values (3, 'InStock')
1 rows inserted.
> commit
committed.
> -- change number of items for Chairs
> update item set num=5 where stock_id = (select stock_id from stock where name = 'Chair')
1 rows updated.
> commit
committed.
> -- state is now wrong
> select st.name, i.num, s.val 
from stock st, state s, item i
where st.stock_id = i.stock_id
and st.stock_id = s.stock_id
NAME                        NUM VAL                
-------------------- ---------- --------------------
Ball                         35 InStock              
Chair                         5 OutOfStock           
Pen                           1 InStock              

> -- now we need to maintain "State" table
> update state st
set (st.val) = (
  select decode(i.num, 0, 'OutOfStock','InStock')
  from item i
  where i.stock_id = st.stock_id
)
-- only update those with invalid state values
where exists (
  select stock_id
  from item i
  where i.stock_id = st.stock_id
  and st.val <> decode(i.num, 0, 'OutOfStock','InStock')
)
1 rows updated.
> commit
committed.
> -- state is corrected
> select st.name, i.num, s.val 
from stock st, state s, item i
where st.stock_id = i.stock_id
and st.stock_id = s.stock_id
NAME                        NUM VAL                
-------------------- ---------- --------------------
Ball                         35 InStock              
Chair                         5 InStock              
Pen                           1 InStock
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I cannot change this, it is a application database for a package called Siebel. That is the way there tables work.

Comment: @loosebruce I understand.  My answer (see update statement above) should work for you WITHOUT changing your current schema.  I only commented that a state table you have to maintain isn't a good design approach.